# click on Element

Tags: javascript, loops, toggle

I have a problem, I have a gallery, and when you click on a picture, the picture wants to be bigger and if you click again, the picture has to be smaller, but it didn't work, can someone fix my code for me ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/200/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/200/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/450/200/200" alt="">
  </div>

  <script>

var img=document.getElementsByClassName("pic");
for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
  img[i].addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
    var evento=event.target;
    evento.style.width="700px"
  })
}

img[i].addEventListener("click",(eventen)=>{
  var eventen=eventen.target;
  eventen.style.width="200px"
})

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want, when I click on another picture, the previous picture should be small again,

Comment: I have updated my answer for that, [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610502/click-on-element/68610584#68610584)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll and toggle class on picture click

```css
.pic-large {
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <div id="content">
      <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200" alt="">
      <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/200/200" alt="">
      <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/200/200" alt="">
      <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/450/200/200" alt="">

   </div>

<script>
  let img = document.querySelectorAll(".pic");
  
  img.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", (event)=> {
      let cur = event.target.classList.contains('pic-large')
      img.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('pic-large'))
      cur ? event.target.classList.remove('pic-large') : 
      event.target.classList.add('pic-large')
    })
  })
  /*let img = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");
  for(let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
    img[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      let cur = event.target.classList.contains('pic-large');
      for(let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        img[i].classList.remove('pic-large')
      }
      cur ? event.target.classList.remove('pic-large') : event.target.classList.add('pic-large')
    })
  }*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want, when I click on another picture, the previous picture should be small again,

Comment: Thank you, is there an option to do this example using for Loop or just using Foreach?

Comment: Yes, there is, I supplemented the answer, so in commented part you can look at same thing with loop

Answer (score 0):

You cant add 2 of the same click handlers on the same image, so in your click handler you need to check if the width is already 700px if so make it 200 otherwise make it 700

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/200/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/200/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/450/200/200" alt="">
  </div>

  <script>
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");
    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      img[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        var evento = event.target;
        Object.values(img).forEach((im) => im.style.width = "200px")
        evento.style.width = "700px"
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = content>
        <img class = pic src = https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200>
        <img class = pic src = https://picsum.photos/id/400/200/200>
        <img class = pic src = https://picsum.photos/id/201/200/200>
        <img class = pic src = https://picsum.photos/id/450/200/200>
    </div>

    <script>
        let images = document.getElementsByClassName("pic")

        for (image of images) {
            image.addEventListener("click", event => {
                let evento = event.target

                if (evento.style.width == "700px") evento.style.width = "200px"
                else evento.style.width = "700px"
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

with event delegation...

```js
const AllPics = document.querySelectorAll('#content img.pic')

document.querySelector('#content').onclick = evt =>
  {
  if (!evt.target.matches('img.pic')) return
  
  if ( evt.target.classList.toggle('big700') )
    AllPics.forEach(img=>
      {
      if (img != evt.target)
        img.classList.toggle('big700',false)
      })
  }
```

```css
.big700 { width:700px }
#content img.pic { cursor : pointer }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/450/200/200" alt="">
</div>
```